# Batch sync up - slow performance/performance improvement

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

1. Version of Mobile SDK Used: 9.2.1
2. Issue found in Native App or Hybrid App: Native App
3. OS Version: All
4. Device: All
5. Steps to reproduce: syncUp

We use SmartSync/SmartStore to sync offline data with Salesforce. However, we notice the slow performance of this process. It was implemented a long time ago in https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/blob/9f4daa6f28fb1dbeaeee0e611bd550ece66e408e/libs/MobileSync/MobileSync/Classes/Target/SFSyncUpTarget.h however, it does not solve our problem.

The Composite API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) used in this implementation creates 25 subrequests (one record per subrequest) that are sent to Salesforce. However, each of these subrequests is handled separately, not as a batch (below example)

```
{
   "method":"POST",  
   "url":"\/services\/data\/v49.0\/composite",  
   "body":{  
      "compositeRequest":[
         {
            "method":"PATCH",
            "url":"\/services\/data\/v49.0\/sobjects\/xxx\/ExternalId__c\/123",
            "body":{
               "Name" : "name1",
               "RelatedRecord__r":{
                  "ExternalId__c":"12345"
               }
            },
            "referenceId":"local_1"
         },
        {
            "method":"PATCH",
            "url":"\/services\/data\/v49.0\/sobjects\/xxx\/ExternalId__c\/1234",
            "body":{
               "Name" : "name1",
               "RelatedRecord__r":{
                  "ExternalId__c":"12345"
               }
            },
            "referenceId":"local_2"
        }
     ],
   "allOrNone":false
   }
}
```

As an effect, we are getting the following stamps from the database.

[image]

The sync of 411 records started at 11:33:54 (first record) and was finished at 11:36:28 (last record) so very long time - about 2:30 minutes.

We are using Salesforce SDK in 9.2.1, it is our custom application with SDK package. We use SmartStore and SmartSync. Did you observe the same issue?

Created issues in github
https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/issues/3496
https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues/2293

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. There doesn't appear to be a question here. You should probably [edit] the question to frame a question around improving performance of the cited SDK sync code then move the answer information you have included in the question out into a self-answer.

Comment: Have you thought about using [briefcases](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.briefcase_builder_overview.htm&type=5)?

Comment: Thanks, @PhilW, adjusted to your reco, hope that works now. I think Briefcases works with Field Service mobile app, while we have our custom one working on SmartSync/SmartStore. Not sure if we can connect the briefcase to our custom app if the application does not have code to communicate with it. I guess that briefcase itself it not within SDK library: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/intro.htm

Answer (score 1):

After investigation, we would recommend implementing different API for data synchronization https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_upsert.htm

```
PATCH /composite/sobjects/xxx/ExternalId__c

{
    "allOrNone" : false,
    "records" : [{
        "attributes" : {"type" : "xxx"},
        "Name" : "name1",
        "ExternalId__c" : "123",
        "RelatedRecord__r":{
                  "ExternalId__c":"12345"
               }
    }, {
        "attributes" : {"type" : "xxx"},
        "Name" : "name1",
        "ExternalId__c" : "1234",
        "RelatedRecord__r":{
                  "ExternalId__c":"12345"
               }
    }]
}
```

In that case, we can push as one batch - not single records in the different sub-requests:

[image]

It can be a game-changer in the sync process.